# jenkins - Triggering build from Git - Security violation

Tags: security, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins i will be providing the below url for triggering builds remotely from Git and also in Git we will be mentioning this url in the Git Hooks section.

Trigger builds remotely.
http://someserver:someport/job/myjobname/build?token=somegeneratedtoken

Is this not a security violation as we are exposing the server through this url?

Comment: You plan to expose the full server or only a sub-path?

Comment: Is it safe to expose the server in payload url section of webhook in github?